# Measure a circuit (small system current consumption using power source

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, bluetooth, low-power, bluetooth-low-energy

I am powering a chip (CY8CKIT-143A). It is a BLE module + micro-controller. I am using it to transmit the data of a thermistor. I am using a DC power supply (Agilent E3644A).

[image]

I am powering the system with 3 Volts.

Can I use the current reading on the screen as an accurate measurement of how much the system is pulling? Is this a true measurement of required power for the system or do I need to measure across certain pins on the chip?

Comment: it's highly accurate, but not very precise or time-discrete to use with battery-powered end devices.

Comment: @dandavis I don't understand. What do you mean highly accurate, but not very precise?

Comment: I mean that for many BLE devices, people usually want to know microamps, your meter is only milliamps. If that's enough precision for your needs, then you're ok using the built-in. On a good PSU like that it's likely to be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to give you very meaningful information as it is likely averaging and rounding the actual current, ignoring any transients that are common to microcontrollers with radios. I highly recommend Nordic's Power Profiler 2 - it's on the pricey side ($99 right now) but comes with few software you can use to log power down to the nanoamp range